# Setting file access time, modification time

Tags: c, time, posix

I have a list of files in a mounted drive. I am trying to set access and modify time.

This is the stat information before using utime to modify

```
Access: 2020-07-28 15:06:51.000000000 +0530
Modify: 2020-07-28 15:06:51.000000000 +0530
```

After using utime here is the stat information.

```
Access: 2020-07-28 21:20:47.-469639744
Modify: 2020-07-28 21:20:47.-469740064
```

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utime.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *filepath = "pathToFile/file";
    struct utimbuf ubuf;
    ubuf.actime = time(NULL) + (time_t)(6*60*60);
    ubuf.modtime = time(NULL) + (time_t)(6*60*60);
    errno = 0;
    int ret = utime(filepath, &ubuf);
    if (ret == -1) {
        printf("Error is: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    } else {
        puts("No Error!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I retain the time zone info of +0530 here?

Comment: There is no time zone info. it's just `stat` is displaying it that way. Would be strange for `stat` to display timezone of a future date.

Comment: Please pick one language and stick with it. C and C++ are two very different languages with possible different solutions to any given problem. And your code is POSIX specific, so you should probably add the `posix` tag.

Comment: Also note that POSIX marks [`utime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utime.html) as obsolescent, you shouldn't use it in new code.

Comment: Errors belong on stderr.  `fprintf(stderr, "Error ...`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude didn't know that went through the IBM website which showed this example, what is the recommended way?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes will do that from now on

Comment: @KamilCuk if I run stat after a minute the timezone shows up. Is it normal? the files are on a samba share.

Comment: To change the access time, just open and close the file. To change the modified time, read the first byte and write it back (there might be other less intrusive operations though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no time zone info stored in file timestamps (at least not in a filesystems I worked with). It's just `stat` is displaying it that way.

The relevant code from [`stat.c` `human_time()`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/stat.c#L650):

```
  if (localtime_rz (tz, &t.tv_sec, &tm))
    nstrftime (str, sizeof str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N %z", &tm, tz, ns);
  else
    {
      char secbuf[INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND (intmax_t)];
      sprintf (str, "%s.%09d", timetostr (t.tv_sec, secbuf), ns);
    }
```

Internally all stat "knows" is the timestamp of the file in `struct timespec` format without any timezone information. If the conversion from seconds from the file timestamp to `struct tm` in `localtime_rz()` call succeeds, then the timestamp is printed in a format that includes the `%z` timezone information. If the call fails, then `"%s.%09d"` is used. The timestamp is not stored, it is inferred ("guessed") from the stamp when `stat` displays info about the file.

Comment: Thanks, actually I can see the timestamp now. It's a samba share, it takes a minute for it to change and show the timezone. Is this normal?

Comment: @AAB Caching issues perhaps?